# Botão que quando clicado exibe uma imagem, se clicado novamente exibe outra imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Tudo bem? estou criando um botão que quando clicado exibe uma imagem, e se clicado novamente ele volta pra imagem antiga, isso no angular, atualmente só estou conseguindo pegar a primeira ação, não consigo voltar para primeira imagem.

###### HTML

```
<div (click)="clique()">
  <img src="{{ imagem }}" />
</div>
```

###### TS

```
imagem: string;

clique(): void {
  if(this.imagem) {
    this.imagem = 'imagem1.jpg';
  } else {
    this.imagem = 'imagem2.jpg';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema aí é que como você não atribui nenhum valor ao atributo **imagem** sempre irá cair no `else` pelo fato da variável ser **`undefined`**, uma das maneiras de fazer o que deseja é inserindo mais um atributo que controle qual das duas imagens será renderizada:

##### HTML

```
<div (click)="clique()">
  <img [src]="imagem" />
</div>
```

##### TS

```
imagem: string;
control = false;

clique(): void {
  this.control = !this.control;   // Espero que saiba o que isso faz
  if(this.control) {              // Se control igual true
    this.imagem = 'imagem1.jpg';
  } else {                        // Se control igual false
    this.imagem = 'imagem2.jpg';
  }
}
```

Poder ver um exemplo funcional [aqui](https://ng-run.com/edit/sLpcp1V7ruQXy0ABSYel).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente, e obrigado pela explicação para que eu pudesse perceber meu erro